# Can you use two force:recordData in one lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I want to load the fields of an existing Record into a component, then display that component next to the existing detail of the record. Let the user change what they will then save that form as a new record. I am trying to use Lightning data service. I know how to load a record with force:recordData and how to create a new record. Here I want to do both. Can I use the force:recordData tag twice in one page ? What is a good way to do this ? This is what I have:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId">

<aura:attribute name="clonedExamRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordSaveError" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="existingExam" type="Object"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<force:recordData aura:id="ClonedExamCreator"
    layoutType="FULL"
    targetFields="{!v.clonedExamRecord}"
    targetError="{!v.recordSaveError}"
    mode="EDIT" />  

<force:recordData aura:id="ExamLoader"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  targetFields="{!v.existingExam}"
                  mode="VIEW"/>

<!-- Display an editing form -->
<div class="Record Details">
    <lightning:card iconName="action:edit" title="Cloned Exam">
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
            <lightning:input label="Name" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Name}" placeholder="{!v.existingExam.Name}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:input label="Number of Minutes" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Number_of_Minutes__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:input label="Graded" type="checkbox" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Graded__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:input label="Show One Question at a Time" type="checkbox" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Show_One_Question_at_a_Time__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:input label="Show Score Upon Completion" type="checkbox" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Show_Score_Upon_Completion__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:input label="Randomize Question Order" type="checkbox" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Randomize_Question_Order__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:select label="Status" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Status__c}">
                <option value="Created">Created</option>
                <option value="Sent">Sent</option>
                <option value="Ungraded">Ungraded</option>
                <option value="Graded">Graded</option>
                <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
            </lightning:select>
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Clone" iconName="action:new_campaign" onclick="{!c.createNewExam}" />
        </div>
    </lightning:card>
</div>

<!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors, if any -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordError))}">
    <div class="recordError">
        {!v.recordError}
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper){
      // Prepare a new record from template
    component.find("ClonedExamCreator").getNewRecord(
        "Exam__c", // sObject type (objectApiName)
        null,      // recordTypeId
        false,     // skip cache?
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            //var rec = component.get("v.clonedExamRecord");
            //var error = component.get("v.recordSaveError");
            //if(error || (rec === null)) {
             //   console.log("Error initializing record template: " + error);
             //   return;
            //}
            //console.log("Record template initialized: " + rec.sobjectType);
        })
    );


},

createNewExam : function(component, event, helper){
    component.find("ClonedExamCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {
            if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
                // record is saved successfully
                var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                resultsToast.setParams({
                    "title": "Saved",
                    "message": "The record was saved."
                });
                resultsToast.fire();

            } else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                // handle the incomplete state
                console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.");
            } else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
                // handle the error state
                console.log('Problem saving contact, error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            } else {
                console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + saveResult.state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            }
        });
    }
```

})

Comment: Does it work? If not, what behavior are you observing?

Answer (score 1):

To create a new record, *recordId* attribute must be empty and to load record, *recordId* must have some value. To attain this we need two `force:recordData` tags. So you can use two tags in one lightning component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it worked perfectly. You are right @Novice.

```
<aura:attribute name="clonedExamRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordSaveError" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="existingExam" type="Object"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<force:recordData aura:id="ClonedExamCreator"
    layoutType="FULL"
    targetFields="{!v.clonedExamRecord}"
    targetError="{!v.recordSaveError}"
    mode="EDIT" />  

<force:recordData aura:id="ExamLoader"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  targetFields="{!v.existingExam}"
                  mode="VIEW"/>

<!-- Display an editing form -->
<div class="Record Details">
    <lightning:card iconName="action:edit" title="Cloned Exam">
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
            <lightning:input label="Name" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Name}" placeholder="{!v.existingExam.Name}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:input label="Number of Minutes" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Number_of_Minutes__c}" placeholder="{!v.existingExam.Number_of_Minutes__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:input label="Graded" type="checkbox" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Graded__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:input label="Show One Question at a Time" type="checkbox" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Show_One_Question_at_a_Time__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:input label="Show Score Upon Completion" type="checkbox" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Show_Score_Upon_Completion__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:input label="Randomize Question Order" type="checkbox" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Randomize_Question_Order__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:select label="Status" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Status__c}">
                <option value="Created">Created</option>
                <option value="Sent">Sent</option>
                <option value="Ungraded">Ungraded</option>
                <option value="Graded">Graded</option>
                <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
            </lightning:select>
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Clone" iconName="action:new_campaign" onclick="{!c.createNewExam}" />
        </div>
    </lightning:card>
</div>

<!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors, if any -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordError))}">
    <div class="recordError">
        {!v.recordError}
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

Anyone know how to use placeholder with numbers and checkboxes ?

Comment: I've used force:recordData within an aura:iteration to create separate LDS components for multiple records (such as those in a list of records) so I can catch updates to any of those records and act on them (such as updating the list).  Just a thought if you need to use LDS with multiple records within a component.

Comment: Florissant53, How do you get the ID of a record you just inserted with force:recordData ?

Comment: I haven't used force:recordData for record inserts or updates yet, just for loading records and monitoring them for updates elsewhere in the app via standard or custom components, so I can react to those updates (such as refreshing a component).  One of my components loaded dozens of records at a time, hence my need to put force:recordData within an aura:iteration.  But it's just for monitoring updates, not for inserts or updates.

Comment: Please update this answer to include the actual solution description. No one called "Novice" appears here.